# mysql trigger's locks

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, locks

I have a BEFORE INSERT trigger on a table in my mysql database. What it does is:

1. SELECT a few entries from the current table.
2. Matches them with the values to be inserted by using new.columnname
3. If an overlap is found between values, cancel the INSET query by:

   set msg = "Booking already exists";
   signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
4. If no overlap is found, let the query complete.

However, the trigger is not working as I expected it to be as in very rare cases, it ignores the overlapping values. The only possible scenario I can think of is:

1. Two INSERT queries with overlapping values are being executed with microseconds of time difference between them.
2. The 1st trigger runs and creates a READ lock on the table to SELECT values. No overlap is found and so it releases the READ lock and creates a WRITE lock, so it can now complete the INSERT query. Meanwhile, the second trigger creates its READ lock to SELECT values and selects the existing values. The first trigger hasn't yet written its values in the table.
3. The 1st trigger then writes its values into the table. And then the second trigger writes its value as it hasn't found any overlap either.

I've tested by running two such queries simultaneously numerous times but this has just happened once till yet. But it still has, so I need a way to make sure it never happens again.

One possible scenario in my mind is to lock the table explicitly before running the INSERT query.

So the transaction will look like this:

```
LOCK TABLE t WRITE;
LOCK TABLE t READ;
INSERT INTO t ....;
UNLOCK TABLE t;
```

In this case, my question is:

If now I execute this transaction simultaneously, will the second one be queued or return an error?

Any input will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: So how do you select a few entries,what is the criteria

Comment: I think that using a BEFORE INSERT trigger could be difficult to manage. What if your system tries to insert thousands or millions of rows at the same time? You have to lock your table to read existing records and let the INSERT statements wait (for how much time? It depends on your SELECT query and existing records). The database could suffer in terms of performance. Maybe performing a validation before generating INSERT statements could avoid the use of a trigger and a lock.